# How can I set distance between elements ordered vertically?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have code like that:

```
    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    myPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(myPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JButton button = new JButton("My Button");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("My label!!!!!!!!!!!");

    myPanel.add(button);
    myPanel.add(label);
```

In this way I get elements with no distance between them. I mean, the "top" elements always touches the "bottom" element. How can I change it? I would like to have some separation between my elements?

I think about adding some "intermediate" JPanel (with some size) between my elements. But I do not think it is an elegant way to get the desired effect. Can somebody, please, help me with that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    myPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(myPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JButton button = new JButton("My Button");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("My label!!!!!!!!!!!");

    myPanel.add(button);
    myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
    myPanel.add(label);
```

will be one way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

If you're definitely intending to use `BoxLayout` to layout your panel, then you should have a look at the [How to Use BoxLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) Sun Learning Trail, specifically the [Using Invisible Components as Filler](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler) section.  In short, with `BoxLayout` you can create special invisible components that act as spacers between your other components:

```
container.add(firstComponent);
container.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
container.add(secondComponent);
```

Comment: In this case you could also use Box.createVerticalStrut(5). There is a complementary Box.createHorizontalStrut(int) as well. I prefer these when one of the dimensions is zero.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider GridLayout instead of BoxLayout, it has attributes Hgap and Vgap that let you specify a constant seperation between components.

```
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, 1);
layout.setVgap(10);
myPanel.setLayout(layout);
myPanel.add(button);
myPanel.add(label);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Box` class as an invisible filler element. This is how Sun recommends you do it.

[BoxLayout tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).