# How can I put a horizontal line between vertically ordered elements?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, line

I have a set of vertically ordered elements. They are displayed with the following code:

```
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(myPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
JButton button = new JButton("My Button");
JLabel label = new JLabel("My label!!!!!!!!!!!");
myPanel.add(button);
myPanel.add(label);
```

I would like to put a horizontal line between my elements (something like `<hr>` in html). Does anybody know how it can be done?

Comment: Yet again the answer is found in the Swing tutorial. This guy continually refuses to read the tutorial. Check out his comment in this posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561305/how-can-i-set-distance-between-elements-ordered-vertically, where he states that his time is more important than ours, which is why he doesn't bother to read the tutorial. It amazes me he still gets answers spoon fed to him.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use a JSeparator. Check out this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/separator.html) on it.

But for a quick answer, just use the following code:

```
myPanel.add(button);
myPanel.add(new JSeparator());
myPanel.add(label);
```

Comment: And if you don't want "infinite" space between the button and label, assign the separator to a variable and call `separator.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 20))` on it (adjust for how much space you need and whether the separator is horizontal or vertical)

Answer (score 3):

Create a JSeparator and add it between button and label.

Comment: This works, but pushes following added elements to the bottom of the box layout. How can this be avoided?