# Adding space between buttons in VBox

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I have a collection of buttons:

```
VBox menuButtons = new VBox();
menuButtons.getChildren().addAll(addButton, editButton, exitButton);
```

I want to add some spacing between these buttons, without using a CSS style sheet. I think there should be a way to do this.

`setPadding();` is for the `Button`s in the `VBox`.
`setMargin();` should be for the `VBox` itself. But I didn't find a way for the spacing between the buttons.

I'm glad for any ideas. :)

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561305/how-can-i-set-distance-between-elements-ordered-vertically

Comment: @Andy: No, I'm working with JavaFX and not with Swing at the moment, but thanks! :)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`VBox` supports spacing out of the box:

```
VBox menuButtons = new VBox(5);
```

or

```
menuButtons.setSpacing(5);
```

Comment: Thx... :$ I tought this would be the number of elements in it. Nerver tought that this'd be so simple.

Comment: Btw: In FXML it looks like this: `<VBox spacing="5">...</VBox>`

Comment: the amounts of votes on this straightforward question really put this class' API in perspective :)

Comment: @codepleb the FXML version is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 20):

Just call `setSpacing` method and pass some value.
Example with `HBox` (it's same for `VBox`):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBoxBuilder;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SpacingDemo extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Spacing demo");

        Button btnSave = new Button("Save");
        Button btnDelete = new Button("Delete");
        HBox hBox = HBoxBuilder.create()
                .spacing(30.0) //In case you are using HBoxBuilder
                .padding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5))
                .children(btnSave, btnDelete)
                .build();

        hBox.setSpacing(30.0); //In your case

        stage.setScene(new Scene(hBox, 320, 240));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

And this is how it looks:

Without of spacing:

[image]

With spacing:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! Big Thx! :)
I would have chosen this, if Sergey Grinev didn't give a solution where I can set this directly in the constructor.

Comment: Builder are depreciated in javafx 8, you should use standard way to create the object and set its spacing. see [this post on oracle forum](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2544323)

Comment: @FloC I believe you. But I'm using Java 1.7 update 21. Nevertheless, thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 16):

If you're using FXML, use the `spacing` attribute:

```
<VBox spacing="5" />
```

Answer (score 9):

As others have mentioned you can use `setSpacing()`.

However, you can also use `setMargin()`, it is not for the pane (or box in your words), it is for individual `Node`s. `setPadding()` method is for the pane itself. In fact, `setMargin()` takes a node as a parameter so you can guess what it's for.

For example:

```
HBox pane = new HBox();
Button buttonOK = new Button("OK");
Button buttonCancel = new Button("Cancel");
/************************************************/
pane.setMargin(buttonOK, new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0)); //This is where you should be looking at.
/************************************************/
pane.setPadding(new Insets(25));
pane.getChildren().addAll(buttonOK, buttonCancel);
Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
primaryStage.setTitle("Stage Title");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

You could get the same result if you replaced that line with

```
pane.setSpacing(10);
```

If you have several nodes that should be spaced, `setSpacing()` method is far more convenient because you need to call `setMargin()` for each individual node and that would be ridiculous. However, `setMargin()` is what you need if you need *margins*(duh) around a node that you can determine how much to each side because `setSpacing()` methods places spaces **only** in between nodes, not between the node and the edges of the window.

Comment: Good post but I think it is a bit cleaner to do `HBox.setMargin(Node, Insets)` rather than `pane.setMargin(Node, Insets)` since `setMargin` is a static function. I don't know if either way makes a practical difference.

Answer (score 3):

The same effect as the `setSpacing` method can also be achieved via css:

```
VBox {
    -fx-spacing: 8;
}
```